# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity and EF Core, Reset User Password while testing old password

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Trying to do Password Reset using UserManager ChangePasswordAsync

```
     public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePasswordAsync(ChangePwdInfo info)
     {
        var result = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(CurrentUser, info.PasswordCurrent, info.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            LogInformation("Password changed successfully");
            return Ok();
        }
        var err = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
        if (err?.Code == "PasswordMismatch")
        {
            return SystemInfo("Current Password was not correct", $"Change password called with incorrect current password");
        }

        return SystemError($"Password change {result}: ", $"Change password failed {result.Errors.FirstOrDefault()?.Description}");
    }
```

Getting error on ChangePasswordAsync:

> The instance of entity type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

So it would appear the _userManager is Tracking the ApplicationUser but I don't want/need it to. However there is no `.AsNoTracking()` option, so how do I tell EF and to not track in this instance?

I do have a reference to the shared dbContext that _userManager uses, so I tried to clear the Changing Tracking with the following, (after the CheckPasswordSignInAsync), but that made no difference.

```
dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that elsewhere I was getting the Current logged in user, and was using .AsNoTracking() as I do not need it tracked.

```
_currentUser = _userManager.Users.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userEmail);
```

But when I remove the .AsNoTracking() from the above, the Password reset works ok.

However, surely there should be a way to tell _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync to not track the user, or what am I missing?